# Unexpected behavior for `iloc` assignment

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code snippet:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(i,i+1) for i in range(0,20,2)])
perm = list(np.random.permutation(10))
perm_df = df.iloc[perm, :]
perm_df.iloc[perm, :] = perm_df.values
```

The goal is simple, to permute a DataFrame once, and then bring it back to its original form.

No chain indexing is used, and no warning is thrown.

The result is the following

```
    0   1
6  10  11
8   2   3
2   4   5
5  16  17
1  12  13
0  10  11
7  12  13
4  12  13
9  16  17
3  16  17
```

I suspected that it might have something to do with the integer index, but converting it to `str` type didn't help.

Next, I ended up following the golden rule of copying before assigning:
`perm_df.iloc[perm, :] = perm_df.copy().values`

and ended up with the (partially) expected result:

```
    0   1
6   0   1
8   2   3
2   4   5
5   6   7
1   8   9
0  10  11
7  12  13
4  14  15
9  16  17
3  18  19
```

I understand that the index won't change following an `iloc` assignment, so `reset_index` will do the trick.

So the question is, why does `perm_df.iloc[perm, :] = perm_df.values` results in such behavior? It is definitely related to the fact that I used the same `DataFrame`, but I expected `values` to just return a copy of the content.

My conjecture is that under the hood, `values` changes during the assignment. Is it a known behavior?

Comment: Btw this isnt related to pandas, its numpy. Try `x = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2); y = x[perm]` what you're doing (and what achieves unwanted results) is `y[perm] = y`, because the index array is being used to edit itself, so it changes as the assignment occurs. What does work is `y[perm] = y.copy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour comes from [line 981](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py#L981) of `pandas/core/internals/blocks.py` the `setitem` function:

```
values[indexer] = value
```

Same setup as before:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(i, i + 1) for i in range(0, 20, 2)])
perm = list(np.random.permutation(10))
perm_df = df.iloc[perm, :]
```

Notice the difference between:

```
value = perm_df.values
values = perm_df.values
values[(perm, slice(None, None, None))] = value
```

`values`:

```
[[ 0  1]
 [10 11]
 [ 4  5]
 [18 19]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]
 [ 8  9]
 [ 8  9]
 [ 8  9]
 [18 19]]
```

And

```
value = perm_df.copy().values
values = perm_df.values
values[(perm, slice(None, None, None))] = value
```

`values`:

```
[[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]
 [12 13]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]
 [18 19]]
```

---

Since arrays are mutable, by not copying the `values`, only one array exists, and that single array is being updated iteratively.

The assignment process looks something like:

`perm`:

```
[9, 5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 0, 8, 6, 3]
```

`values`:

```
[[18 19]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [14 15]  # 4 
 [ 2  3]  # 5 
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [16 17]  # 7 
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [ 6  7]] # 9
```

`0 -> 9`

```
[[18 19]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [14 15]  # 4 
 [ 2  3]  # 5 
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [16 17]  # 7 
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9 ([ 6  7])
```

`1 -> 5`:

```
[[18 19]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [14 15]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 ([ 2  3])
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [16 17]  # 7 
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`2 -> 2`:

```
[[18 19]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 ([ 4  5])
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [14 15]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [16 17]  # 7 
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`3 -> 4`:

```
[[18 19]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [ 8  9]  # 4 ([14 15])
 [10 11]  # 5 
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [16 17]  # 7 
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`4 -> 7`:

```
[[18 19]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [ 8  9]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [ 8  9]  # 7 ([16 17])
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`5 -> 1`:

```
[[18 19]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [ 8  9]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 ([10 11])
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [ 8  9]  # 7 
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`6 -> 0`:

```
[[ 0  1]  # 0 ([18 19])
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [ 8  9]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [ 8  9]  # 7 
 [12 13]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`7 -> 8`:

```
[[ 0  1]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [ 8  9]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 
 [ 0  1]  # 6 
 [ 8  9]  # 7 
 [ 8  9]  # 8 ([12 13])
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`8 -> 6`:

```
[[ 0  1]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [ 8  9]  # 3 
 [ 8  9]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 
 [ 8  9]  # 6 ([ 0  1])
 [ 8  9]  # 7 
 [ 8  9]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

`9 -> 3`:

```
[[ 0  1]  # 0 
 [10 11]  # 1 
 [ 4  5]  # 2 
 [18 19]  # 3 ([ 8  9])
 [ 8  9]  # 4 
 [10 11]  # 5 
 [ 8  9]  # 6 
 [ 8  9]  # 7 
 [ 8  9]  # 8 
 [18 19]] # 9
```

When there are two different arrays this issue does not occur as the array is not being overwritten as it is being restructured (which is why assigning to a copy functions as expected).

---

**Note** calling `copy` on the DataFrame immediately after `iloc` does **not** resolve this issue as the duplicate reference to the same (underlying) *array* is the issue, not the reference to former DataFrame (`df`):

```
perm_df = df.iloc[perm, :].copy()
perm_df.iloc[perm, :] = perm_df.values
```

`perm_df`:

```
[[ 0  1]
 [10 11]
 [ 4  5]
 [18 19]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]
 [ 8  9]
 [ 8  9]
 [ 8  9]
 [18 19]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I suspected. To wrap it up, both ```iloc``` and ```values``` return a reference to the underlying array, is that correct?
In addition, as far as I understand this issue is somewhat specific to the permutation usage - in case we use some index preserving transformation on ```values```, we're safe and sound.

Comment: Yes `values` returns a reference to the underlying array, and `iloc` modifies that same array. This issue actually applies to any `numpy` array that modifies itself. (which is what this issue resolves to)

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas, indexing a DataFrame returns a reference to the initial DataFrame. Thus, changing the subset will change the initial DataFrame. Thus, you'd want to use the copy if you want to make sure the initial DataFrame shouldn't change. Consider the following code:

```
df = DataFrame({'x': [1,2]})
df_sub = df[0:1]
df_sub.x = -1
print(df)
```

You'll get

```
x
0 -1
1  2
```

while the following leaves df unchanged

```
df_sub_copy = df[0:1].copy()
df_sub_copy.x = -1
```

pandas uses a form known as a deep copy
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Comment: The problem here wasn't about which object is being changed, but rather how it was changed. The fact that the change takes place iteratively + that it refers to previously changed entries during that iteration, is the cause of the discrepancy.